# Where and how do I obtain and install certificates to a new installation of OpenSSL?

Tags: configuration, openssl, ssl, browser, certificates

I have just compiled OpenSSL and the Lynx web browser. I would like to browse HTTPS websites. It is my understanding that I need to get certificates from the CAs those sites use and that I also need some sort of certificate of my own. The web browser calls OpenSSL properly, but I can't browse the internet because I don't have an initiali list of CA certificates.

Does anyone have documentation that explains how to get these certificates and get OpenSSL to consume them?

Thanks

Comment: Please state the browser. Different browsers use different trust stores.

Comment: It is the Lynx browser.

Answer (score 2):

To make your browser dealing with SSL/TLS you must install in your browser root certificates from different certification authorities. With those certificates your browser will recognize signet keys and will accept them. You can [check here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/Included_Certificates) for the list of CAs, installed in Mozilla as well as certificates itself.

P.S. For installing certificates you must check your browser documentation

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have documentation that explains how to get these certificates and get OpenSSL to consume them?

From Lynx's [`README.sslcerts`](http://lynx.browser.org/current/README.sslcerts):

> PRELIMINARY PROCEDURES:
>
> It is assumed that openssl has been installed correctly, that the
>   default cert directory is /usr/local/ssl/certs, (it's often
>   /etc/ssl/certs, but we need a point of departure for the discussion)
>   and that lynx has been compiled --with-ssl.
>
> The default location for certs on your system may be different, or
>   there may not be one. You will have to substitute that location for
>   /usr/local/ssl/certs in the following instructions, and/or set
>   environment variables.
>
> To determine the default location for certs on your system you may run
>   the following command:
>
> ```
> strings libcrypto.a  | grep -in cert | less
> ```
>
> Look in this output for `SSL_CERT_DIR` and `SSL_CERT_FILE`, and the lines
>   just above them. This is your default location, respectively, for
>   certificates, and the CA cert bundle, cert.pem. You will need to know
>   where libcrypto.a is found of course.
>
> Example output:
>
> ```
> 7490:/etc/ssl/certs
> 7491:/etc/ssl/cert.pem
> 7492:SSL_CERT_DIR
> 7493:SSL_CERT_FILE
> ```
>
> Other possible example output:
>
> ```
> 31555:/usr/local/ssl/certs
> 31556:/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem
> 31557:SSL_CERT_DIR
> 31558:SSL_CERT_FILE
> ```
>
> Note that when OpenSSL is installed, the c_rehash utility is installed
>   in a bin directory (default `/usr/local/ssl/bin`).  You will need to
>   know where it is on your system. The command:
>
> ```
> whereis c_rehash
> ```
>
> will probably give useful results.
>
> Note also that there is no CA cert bundle distributed with OpenSSL.
>   The OpenSSL team specifically decided NOT to do that. Getting a set of
>   trusted certificates is left up to the installer.
>
> It is no longer a fairly trivial procedure to pull the bundle of
>   trusted root certs out of a recent version of Internet Explorer.
>   Multiple certificates are no longer exportable as a DER formatted
>   file; extraction of a single certificate is the only export for DER,
>   and DER is what converts to PEM.
>
> Users with access to Apple OS X can export all certificates from
>   Keychain Access System Roots as a .pem file. Place this in
>   SSL_CERT_DIR and hash it and you're done.
>
> The MirOS BSD project also provides them. The procedure to convert and
>   install them is detailed later in this document, and if you simply
>   need to have commercially provided certificates trusted by lynx, you
>   can skip down a few lines to the INSTALLING OR UPDATING THE CA BUNDLE
>   section.
>
> Extracted Mozilla cert bundles are available for download from the
>   curl project http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html along with a
>   script to extract from Mozilla source.